# Is it possible in iOS to have one model/view and create a second view that replicates first view automatically on second screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Let's say I have created a model and a view for an iPad. If I have a second screen and want to replicate that view on that second screen is there a facility to do so automatically in iOS (getting automatic mirroring of first view in second view in REAL TIME) ?

Does this mechanism work for both vga and airplay ?

Seems this question is too hard nobody seems to know ?

To precise the first View must stay on iPad and the second view will be on second view and SYNCHRONIZED with first view (same model). ie When User modifies First View, Second View should show same update.

My views would not contain only images, they can contain anything (fields, webview, buttons etc.)

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do? We may be able to suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: I want to show 2 views one on the iPad, one on a second bigger screen through VGA or AirPlay, the views show exactly the same content and second view should update like first view when user changes something. My view does not contain image, it can contain anything (fields, webview, buttons etc.)

Comment: This is done automatically for you by the operating system. You don't need to do anything to support it.

Comment: Do you have a ref doc about this ? This is clearly not obvious as in MVC with 2 views you would have to update the two views yourself so I would be surprised if the OS could do that without explicitely tell her somehow.

Comment: Screen mirroring is a feature of the iPad. It is done by default on (IIRC) iPad 2 and newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have not understood your question completely.
do you want same view in second screen as first view or you want make mirror effect of first view in second view?

if you want the same view as first view in sceond view, then directly get the object as first view and add it as subview in second view.

if you want to create mirror effect then you have write a logic code, i dont know there is any third party library for that,

Please do explain your question

Comment: To precise the first View must stay on iPad and the second view will be on second view and SYNCHRONIZED with first view (same model). ie When User modifies First View, Second View should show same update. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: My view does not contain image, it can contain anything (fields, webview, buttons etc.)

Comment: yes you can do,i have tried with sample app containing one label in first view when you tap on first view you will get second view as model with same state as first view

Comment: Great it works seems simple enough "get the object as first view and add it as subview in second view." but I'm total newbie, could you I download your helloworld project somewhere ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but [ReflectionView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/ReflectionView) does something very similar.  You may be able to adapt it to solve your problem.

Comment: Don't think this would "solve" the problem, but certainly could lead in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure you read my question: by mirroring I rather meant replicating :)

Comment: As I understand it, ReflectionView replicates the view and then transforms the replicated image to be upside-down.  You can get replication working by omitting the second step.

Comment: My view does not contain image, it can contain anything (fields, webview, buttons etc.)

Comment: I believe ReflectionView works with any view, rather than just images.

Comment: Great but the inverted effect is actually annoying :) Also will it update real-time when first view update ?

Comment: You should be able to omit the inverted effect. It will update in real time if it's in dynamic mode.